# what does "free" in context-free languages conceptually mean?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a Context Free Grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713240/what-is-a-context-free-grammar)

I can not understand the conceptual meaning of "free" in context free grammar or language? what is free?

Comment: no definitely not. The question is the meaning of free. if you read the answers on that link, they all explain context free grammar without using "free" word. "free" is only mentined in the name.  for example why is not it named as context-dependant grammar?

Comment: thanks everyone who voted for duplication!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context-free is in contrast to context-sensitive. While a context-sensitive grammar has rules of the form

```
αAβ → αγβ
```

a context-free one has rules conforming to

```
A → γ
```

i.e. A is derivable to γ independent (free) of the context of α and β.

The Wikipedia article on the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) explains it in more detail.